# How to construct a FOR JSON that converts a TOP 1 record into a json object (instead of a json array)

Tags: sql-server, json, json-path

I want to use a `JSON_QUERY` with a `SELECT TOP 1` query such that the resultant json has that top 1 record in object form, instead of in table form?

For example, the following query ([live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/751b7/19)):

```
CREATE TABLE Trees
(
    [Id] INT,
    [Type] NVARCHAR(100),
    [Height] DECIMAL(2,1)
);


INSERT INTO Trees ([Id], [Type], [Height])
VALUES 
(1, 'Palm', 5.5), 
(2, 'Pine', 6.2), 
(3, 'Apple', 2.5), 
(4, 'Japanese Cedar', 0.5), 
(5, 'Spanish Fir', 0.6);


SELECT
  highestTree = JSON_QUERY(
      (
         SELECT TOP 1
         Id as id,
         Type as type,
         Height as height
         FROM Trees 
         WHERE Height = (SELECT Max(Height) FROM Trees)
         FOR JSON PATH
      )
  ),
  lowestTree  = JSON_QUERY(
      (
         SELECT TOP 1
         Id as id,
         Type as type,
         Height as height
         FROM Trees 
         WHERE Height = (SELECT MIN(Height) FROM Trees)
         FOR JSON PATH
      )
 )
FOR JSON
  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
;
```

outputs:

```
{"highestTree":[{"id":2,"type":"Pine","height":6.2}],"lowestTree":[{"id":4,"type":"Japanese Cedar","height":0.5}]}
```

But I want:

```
{"highestTree":{"id":2,"type":"Pine","height":6.2},"lowestTree":{"id":4,"type":"Japanese Cedar","height":0.5}}
```

Comment: Side note: Instead of that subquery `WHERE Height = (SELECT Max(Height) FROM Trees)`, just do `ORDER BY Height DESC` and for `lowest` do `ORDER BY Height ASC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
SELECT
  highestTree = JSON_QUERY(
      (
         SELECT TOP 1
         Id as id,
         Type as type,
         Height as height
         FROM Trees 
         WHERE Height = (SELECT Max(Height) FROM Trees)
         FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )
  ),
  lowestTree = JSON_QUERY(
      (
         SELECT TOP 1
         Id as id,
         Type as type,
         Height as height
         FROM Trees 
         WHERE Height = (SELECT MIN(Height) FROM Trees)
         FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )
 )
FOR JSON
  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
;
```

Result:

```
{"highestTree":{"id":2,"type":"Pine","height":6.2},"lowestTree":{"id":4,"type":"Japanese Cedar","height":0.5}}
```